# Zip deploy Angular App and it's API in same folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

New to Azure Zip deploy. Zip file getting deployed and UI gets loaded. But the webservice endpoint cannot be accessed by the Angular App.

Deployment gets into this folder in wwwroot: Some.App.Here

[image]

API tries to access like:
[https://web_app_service.azurewebsites.net/some.app.here/api/{controller_name}](https://web_app_service.azurewebsites.net/some.app.here/api/%7Bcontroller_name%7D)

But get's 404 for those. How should I configure these virtual paths? Do I need the deployment folder in lowercase too?

Answer (score 0):

Got this resolved by making the deployment folder to have lower case letters. It's bit wired but dont have time to inspect more.